# How to install Android apps in television set-top boxes

Tags: android-tv, smart-tv, google-tv, amazon-fire-tv, amazon-fire-tv-stick

I am running a set-top box from a provider called Sky, and, this, is in turn connected to an Android television.

I can chromecast YouTube videos from my Android smartphone to the Android television (without the need to install a separate adapter (this should confirm that my Android television is indeed an Android television).

I don't think chromecast connects directly to the set-top box. I think it connects to the television, overriding the set-top box.

Nevertheless, when I turn on both the television and the set-top box (my Sky, box, ) I can navigate though television programs and to a special apps section, where I can choose from apps such as Netflix, Prime Video, and Rai Play.

I would like to know, is there set-top boxes that allow you to install Android apps onto them and others that don't?

Which ones are they?

How do I install an app on my set-top box?

Is set-top box what it's called (and not satellite dish or descrambler (I believe it's connected to a satellite dish))?

My question is, how do I install an app from Google Play onto my Sky set-top box?

Thanks.

Comment: That depends on the set-top box. A lot of them are running a proprietary OS. Of course you can only install Android apps if it runs an Android based OS (the name may be different). Unfortunately you forgot to add the exact model name of the Sky set-top box, so we can not check what OS it is running...